# Xcode Bot SSH authentication

Tags: xcode6, su, osx-server, xcode-bots

Hey guys so I have an xcode bot problem. Basically I have a bot that requires a pre-script to be ran. This script runs the command a git submodule init and update, and gets an ssh authentication error.

On the os x server machine it self the appropriate ssh keys have been set on the user admin (tested). In xcode on my machine the server is connect as the user admin. However it seems like when the script is being run it is not being run as admin(tested by creating a text file in ~ and wasnt there after). I was wondering if it was possible to su in the script, i've looked online and it seems like it wouldn't be possible because I don't know what user xcode bot is running the script as (my guess is its running as Guess)

Any advice on this? Or on a way to run the command as a different user(must be in the script)

Answer (score 0):

_xcsbuildd is the account which the bot runs under. Make sure that account has the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode server runs an integration from a separate user called _xcsbuildd.  If it is possible for you to login remotely to the machine that Xcode Server is running then you can login under that user through the Terminal, and should be able to add or check any ssh keys that are loaded with that user.

Here is a useful blog post on how to do this http://papaanton.com/setting-up-xcode-6-and-apple-server-4-0-for-continues-integration-with-cocoapods/

Scroll down to the part called **Adding additional SSH Key to the Xcode Server**  That should be able to walk you through how to do that.  I know its not an automated script, but its how I was able to get past my SSL issues, and maybe it'll help you as well